# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sc'

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Excuse me.Today i want to run a program about how to create DataFrame with sqlContext in Pyspark.The result is a AttributeError,which is"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sc'"
  My computer is win7,spark's version is 1.6.0 ,and API is python3 .I had google several times and read the Spark Python API Docs,and can not solved the problems.So i look for your help.

my code is that:

```
   #python version is 3.5
   sc.stop()
   import pandas as pd
   import numpy as np
   sc=SparkContext("local","app1"
   data2=[("a",5),("b",5),("a",5)]
   df=sqlContext.createDataFrame(data2)
```

And the result is that:

---

```
    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-19-030b8faadb2c> in <module>()
    5 data2=[("a",5),("b",5),("a",5)]
    6 print(data2)
    ----> 7 df=sqlContext.createDataFrame(data2)

    D:\spark\spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6\python\pyspark\sql\context.py in  createDataFrame(self, data, schema, samplingRatio)
    426             rdd, schema = self._createFromRDD(data, schema, samplingRatio)
    427         else:
    --> 428             rdd, schema = self._createFromLocal(data, schema)
    429         jrdd = self._jvm.SerDeUtil.toJavaArray(rdd._to_java_object_rdd())
    430         jdf = self._ssql_ctx.applySchemaToPythonRDD(jrdd.rdd(), schema.json())

    D:\spark\spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6\python\pyspark\sql\context.py in _createFromLocal(self, data, schema)
   358         # convert python objects to sql data
   359         data = [schema.toInternal(row) for row in data]
   --> 360         return self._sc.parallelize(data), schema
   361 
   362     @since(1.3)

    D:\spark\spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6\python\pyspark\context.py in parallelize(self, c, numSlices)
   410         [[], [0], [], [2], [4]]
   411         """
   --> 412         numSlices = int(numSlices) if numSlices is not None else self.defaultParallelism
   413         if isinstance(c, xrange):
   414             size = len(c)

   D:\spark\spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6\python\pyspark\context.py in     defaultParallelism(self)
  346         reduce tasks)
  347         """
  --> 348         return self._jsc.sc().defaultParallelism()
  349 
  350     @property

 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sc'
```

I am so fuzzed that i had created the "sc" in fact,why does it show the Error of"'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sc'"?

​

Comment: Why do you stop `SparkContext` (`sc.stop()`)?

Comment: if you don't add sc.stop(),it will raise the error :`ValueError: Cannot run multiple SparkContexts at once; existing SparkContext(app=PySparkShell, master=local[*]) created by <module> at D:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\py3compat.py:186`.

Comment: Let me rephrase. Why do you stop context and create a new one.

Answer (score 1):

This should work (except in the code you have a missing ')' in the end of sc creation which I imagine is a type). You can try creating sc as follows:

```
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("app1").setMaster("local")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

BTW sc.stop means you already have a spark context which is true if you used pyspark but not if you use spark-submit. It is better to use SparkContext.getOrCreate which works in both cases.

Comment: Thank for your help.I just took you answer and updated my code.But it raise a Error:"NameError: name 'SparkConf' is not defined".I am sorry that  I don't know how to edit my new code and result in the Comment frame.

Comment: You need to import it: import pyspark.SparkConf

Comment: after importing the sparkconf,it worked.But,it raises a "Py4JJavaError ".I had install py4j module and it succed.The error Traceback is long and huge.some traceback is here:`Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-e49631c4d106> in <module>()
      4 sc.stop()
      5 conf = SparkConf().setAppName("app1").setMaster("local")
----> 6 sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
      7 data2=[("a",5),("b",5),("a",5)]
      8 print(data2)` .

Comment: How are you running it? I mean the command line command to run the script?

Comment: my running way is "Jupyter Notebook+pyspark".That is said:jupyter notebook is used as pyspark shell.I think it neccesary to show my code to you.Meanwhile,the result has changed. code:                           `import pandas as pd
from pyspark import SparkConf
import numpy as np
sc.stop()
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("app1").setMaster("local")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf) 
print(sc)
data2=[("a",5),("b",5),("a",5)]
print(data2)
df=sqlContext.createDataFrame(data2)` .

Comment: the result is that:`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sc'`,where error happend in `df=sqlContext.createDataFrame(data2)`.I am so sorry,i will leave my computer to eat dinner.it will be late. I am so grateful to your patient help!!!!!!

Comment: how are you configuring jupyter to run with pyspark?

Comment: Firstly, I open windows Control Panel's System Setting and find out the environment variable setting  .secondly,in the system variable setting,creating a new variable named"PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON",values "Jupyter".Meanwhile,creating another new variable named"PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS",values "notebook".Then click yes and shutdown.Thirdly,copy the folder named"E:\spark\python\pyspark"  to another folder named "D:\anaconda\Lib\site-packages" .Finally,configuring the file name"spark-env" under the folder named "E:spark\conf". And open anoconda prompt and input "pyspark" ,then it start work.

Comment: if you do not define the environment variables and just use pyspark with the defaults (i.e. not notebook but rather in the command line) does it work? It could be an issue of spark not installed correctly and therefore it cannot create the spark context jvm. Or even better, try to do spark-submit for one of the examples.

Comment: i must try it tomorrow!now it is 23:15 pm in China,and school will shutdown our light and we are suppose to sleep by the school rules.Tomorrow i will try it by your advice!!!Thank you a lot!!

Comment: Can you update the original post, if something has changed? How did you import sparkconf??

Answer (score 1):

Here is a minimal example that worked for me. I am not sure, why you imported pandas in the first place, if you are not using it afterwards. I guess your intention was to create a DataFrame from a pandas object. Therefore here is an example to generate a spark-DataFrame from a pandas-Dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark import SQLContext
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 3]})
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
sqlContext.createDataFrame(df)
```

I am running spark in a jupyter notebook too.

Answer (score 0):

I believe we are getting the error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sc'" because we were running two SparkContexts at the same time.

"A SparkContext represents the connection to a Spark cluster, and can be used to create RDD and broadcast variables on that cluster."

also

"Only one SparkContext should be active per JVM. You must stop() the active SparkContext before creating a new one. SparkContext instance is not supported to share across multiple processes out of the box, and PySpark does not guarantee multi-processing execution. Use threads instead for concurrent processing purpose."

In my experience the error was resolved when I restarted my juypter kernal and only ran one SparkContext.

Source of quotes: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.SparkContext.html